# How to sign a message with existing private key by using ECDsa on dotnet core 3.1 MacOS?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, cross-platform, ecdsa

I generated a key by running following command:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -out private.key
```

Worth mentioning that I had to use `secp256k1` curve.

Here is private.key:

```
-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
BgUrgQQACg==
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIMaqRFP3zkco2B2xZaIDQ0/JGcgOqzLPcTTJPqvpu+UooAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAEp0mktO9BMlsVw9lG8EIxr9wZizBHSlUv3VIbf3sTBmCxE4myJvZcgF8b
qDp0T/o9TqnsBw15LU3wdnqV4tJp6w==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Then I tried to sign some random plain-text message:

```
var privateKey = CngKey.Import(privateKeyBytes, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob);
var signer = new ECDsaCng(privateKey);
var signed = signer.SignData(messageBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
```

But encountered a problem when called CngKey.Import: `Windows Cryptography Next Generation (CNG) is not supported on this platform.` (MacOS)

Is there any way to accomplish it cross-platform?

Comment: You could try the Bouncy Castle libs. I'm pretty sure that the normal .NET also doesn't support `secp256k1` curve, only the `secp256r1` curve. .NET's crypto libs are very dated and not very portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  [Maarten Bodewes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/maarten-bodewes) I found [BouncyCastle.NetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.NetCore/) package.

Here is a solution:

```cs
public void Main()
{
    var asymmetricCipherKeyPair = ReadAsymmetricCipherKeyPairFromPem("./key.pem");
    var signature = GetSignature(asymmetricCipherKeyPair.Private, "Some message");
}

private string GetSignature(AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKeyParameter, string message)
{
    var signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA-256withECDSA");

    signer.Init(true, privateKeyParameter);

    signer.BlockUpdate(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message).Length);

    var signature = signer.GenerateSignature();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
}

private AsymmetricCipherKeyPair ReadAsymmetricCipherKeyPairFromPem(string pathToPem)
{
    using var reader = File.OpenText(pathToPem); 
    var keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();

    return keyPair;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This library](https://github.com/starkbank/ecdsa-dotnet) uses pure C# to safely generate keys, sign and verify ECDSA-secp256k1 signatures. Runs on .NET Standard 1.3+. Here is an example:

```
using System;
using EllipticCurve;

PrivateKey privateKey = PrivateKey.fromPem(privateKeyPem);

Signature signature = Ecdsa.sign(message, privateKey);
Console.WriteLine(signature.toBase64());

PublicKey publicKey = privateKey.publicKey();
Console.WriteLine(Ecdsa.verify(message, signature, publicKey));
```